# Как разбить строку на массив (с помощью регулярки)

Tags: javascript

Из дата-атрибута передаю строку (у меня вообще-то это массив, но передается строка) в js.

`["Товар 1", "Товар 3", "Товар 3"]`

Хочу с помощью `split` и регулярного выражения разбить эту строку на массив, но не выходит, подскажите как правильно написать регулярку?

в js ожидается:

`['Товар 1', 'Товар 2', 'Товар 3']`

Comment: Эм... `JSON.parse`?

Comment: `"([а-яА-Я]+ \d+)"` что-то типа такого

Comment: спасибо, регулярка помогла.

Comment: Но в данном случае с такой строкой лучше сделать как написал @Other .... это правильнее

Comment: да, на самом деле данные у меня разные, регулярка сложная получается.

Comment: в таком случае и такая регулярка тоже не всегда выдаст то, что ожидается

Comment: пока, проверяю, все работает

Comment: апостроф в название товара добавь... и убедись, что такая простая регулярка не работает ;)

Answer (score 2):

Эта строка - json и парсить её нужно [соответствующими средствами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
let str = '["Товар 1", "Товар 2", "Товар 3"]';
let arr = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr);

// Обработка ошибок
try {
  console.log(JSON.parse('["Товар 1",'));
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете выбрать все товары следующим образом:

```js
var regex = /[\']([^']*?)[\']/g;
var str = `['Товар 1', 'Товар 2', 'Товар 3', 'Товар Номер4', 'Товар Nuber5', 'Товар 6', 'Товар 7', 'Товар 8', 'Товар-9']`;
var m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Товар: ${m[1]}`);
}
```

Comment: только тут есть небольшой подводный камень с апострафами.
думаю парсилка JSON былабы корректнее.

Comment: Не понимаю, при чём тут вообще апострофы? В вопросе нормальный json-массив с кавычками.

Comment: В примере указаны одинарные кавычки, которые не парсятся функцией JSON.parse, т.к. в json строка должна быть заключена в двойные кавычки. И если от них не избавиться при выводе (например в php экранировать двойные кавычки в строке [\"Товар 1\", \"Товар 3\",,,), но тут есть 2 пути плясать в сторону replace кавычек и потом парсить, или разбирать регулярным выражением.