# Разбить строку на отдельные токены

Tags: python, лексер

Есть строка

```
data = 'Myvar5:=arr[-10];'
```

Как из неё получить `['Myvar5', ':', '=', 'arr', '[', '-', '10', ']', ';']` ?

Comment: Похожее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645106/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: А зачем Вам `:` и `=` разделять? Разве это не один оператор? А `-10`?

Comment: Реализовал так `tokens = [i.strip() for i in re.findall(r"[\w]+|[*\-+()[\]:;=]", data)]`

Answer (score 2):

Можно злоупотребить токенизатором для Питона:

```
import io
import tokenize as T
from operator import itemgetter

def tokenize_string(data):
    tokens = T.tokenize(io.BytesIO(data.strip().encode()).readline)
    next(tokens)  # skip encoding token
    return list(filter(None, map(itemgetter(1), tokens)))  # filter ENDMARKER
```

Пример:

```
>>> tokenize_string('Myvar5:=arr[-10];')
['Myvar5', ':', '=', 'arr', '[', '-', '10', ']', ';']
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас, похоже, стоит задача разбить не на совсем отдельные символы, а на отдельные элементы. Очень похоже, что символы у вас делятся на две группы: 1.Буквы латинского алфавита + цифры 2. Остальные символы
Тогда это становится задачей парсинга. Условно:
Для i-ого символа, если это буква латинского алфавита, то мы записываем его в существующий элемент буфера, иначе создаем новый элемент

```
import string
digits = '0123456789'
data = 'Myvar5:=arr[-10];'
buf = ['']
last = 'c'
for el in data:
    if ((el in string.ascii_letters) or (el in digits)) and (last == 'c'):
        buf[-1] += el
    else:
        buf.append(el)
        last = 'n'
        if ((el in string.ascii_letters) or (el in digits)):
            last = 'c'
data = buf
```

Код получился с костылем, но суть примерно такая